# Representation Theory. Why does $a^{r}b^{s}a^{t}b^{u} = a^{i}b^{j}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I want to know that why we have $a^{r}b^{s}a^{t}b^{u} = a^{i}b^{j}$. Please let me know.

Comment: If you upload entire pages of books, it seems appropriate to specify the source.

Comment: "Representations and Characters of Groups" by James & Liebeck.  I lived in that book for a summer and would recognize it anywhere :)

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x,y\in D_{2n}$. Then for some $r,t \in \{0,1,...,n-1\}$ and for some $s,u \in \{0,1\}$, we know that $x=a^rb^s$ and $y=a^tb^u$. Recall that $D_{2n}$ is a group, and is thus closed under multiplication. Thus, $xy\in D_{2n}$ so that for some $i \in \{0,1,...,n-1\}$ and for some $j \in \{0,1\}$, we have $xy = a^ib^j$. Hence, as desired:
$$
a^rb^sa^tb^u=xy=a^ib^j
$$

Answer (score 2):

First use $b^2=1$ to reduce $b^s$ to at most one $b$. Then write $b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}$ as $ba=a^{-1}b$ (again using $b^2=1$), and use that to successively move the single $b$ to the right.